# Weird link behaviour in Typo3 V10 installation

Tags: url, frontend, typo3, slug

I'm currently working on upgrading a very old Typo3 V6 installation to the newest Typo3 V10. The site is currently working as expected except for one weird thing:

I have a page with the slug-URL-segment `/forschung`. When I call this page from the frontend I get
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znCfq.png). So I thought, it might have something to do with the page permissions but the page is listed as visible and should therefor, since I don't use some kind of login system, be accessible, which is not the case. After some experimenting and trying diffrent things I stumbled over this weird part: If I change the slug-URL-segment to something else e.g. `/forschung-1` the page loads as expected.

Does someone know why this behaviour occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe an old (meanwhile deleted ) has the same slug (or the slug has been generated for it). Have a look at your `pages`-table and rename the former "forschung"-page.

Comment: @JulianHofmann that actually did the trick. I found 5 page entries with the same slug. After figuring out which was the acutall page i deleted the other 4 and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading an old TYPO3 version to v9+ (first version where slugs were introduced) sometimes the upgrade wizard or other automatically processes can generate slugs wrongly. It can happen that the same url is being granted to multiple pages, which is the reason for your inaccessible page (as already mentioned by Julian Hofmann).

If you face this problem again try using `phpMyAdmin`, `Sequel Pro`, `MySQL workbench` or similar tools to check the field `slug` in the database table `pages`, detect duplicates and fix them directly. Otherwise searching for faulty slug in the TYPO3 backend can take some time.